# Array push is not working in my Angular 2 component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have one component like this

```
export class DishComponent implements OnInit{

    @Input() dishID : number
    @Input() showList: boolean = false;
    selectedDishes : Array<any> = [];
    dishSubscribe : Subscription;
    totalDishprice : number;
    dish : any;

    constructor(
        private dishComponentService : DishComponentService,
        private dishService : DishService
    ) {
           this.dishSubscribe = this.dishService.dishItems$.subscribe( data =>{
           this.totalDishprice = data.map( dish => Number(dish.price)).reduce((prev, next) => prev + next, 0);
              console.log(this.totalDishprice);
           })
      }

      ngOnInit(){
          this.dishComponentService.getDishByID(this.dishID).subscribe( response => {
             console.log(response);
             this.dish = response.data[0];
        },(err) =>{
              console.log(err);
        })
     }


     checkDish(dish,isChecked){
         if(isChecked){
            this.selectedDishes.push(dish);
            //this.selectedDishes = [...this.selectedDishes, dish];
            this.dishService.addDish(this.selectedDishes);
         }else{
            let index = this.selectedDishes.findIndex(x => x.id == dish.id);
            this.selectedDishes.splice(index,1);
            this.dishService.addDish(this.selectedDishes);
         }
         console.log(this.selectedDishes);
     }
}
```

and the view is like that,

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="!showList">
     <ion-item class="order-third-dish horizontal-item checkbox-tag">
       <ion-label><span>{{dish?.name}}</span></ion-label>
       <ion-checkbox class="myinput large custom" (ionChange)="checkDish(dish,$event.checked)"  [checked]="isInArray(dish?.id)">
       </ion-checkbox>
     </ion-item>
 </ng-container>

 <ng-container *ngIf="showList">
     <h2 class="item-title">{{dish?.name}}</h2>
      <ion-note class="item-time" item-right>{{dish?.price | currency : 'INR' : true : '.2-2'}}</ion-note>
     <ion-checkbox class="dish_check" (ionChange)="checkDish(dish,$event.checked)" [checked]="isInArray(dish?.id)">
     </ion-checkbox>
 </ng-container>
```

Here I what I am doing is, updating the `selectedDishes` array on every check in the checkbox. But the problem is `push` not working in the `checkDish` function. `this.dishService.addDish(this.selectedDishes);` here I am doing just adding it in a observable.

Comment: create a plunker to reproduce

Comment: Are you getting value of dish in checkdish function ??

Comment: every time I am getting single dish object in checkdish function in console. @Aarsh

Comment: Give me the console output of that @MaantuDas

Comment: {id: "1", name: "Omelettes", price: "35.00", image: false, …} . Every time only one object is reflecting in console

Comment: Have you tried passing the event into your `checkDish()` function and then checking its checked property from inside the function, rather than in your template? Seems like your condition may be failing.

Comment: This look so of `selectedDishes : Array<any> = [];` try `selectedDishes : any[] = [];`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting object there in the dish
`{id: "1", name: "Omelettes", price: "35.00", image: false, …}` like this

So you have an array of the selected dish and then you are pushing an object into it 
If you want to access that dish name and push it to the selected dish then you have to do it like this...

`a = [1,2,3,4,{id:1,name:"aarsh"}]`
if you want to access name then

`a[4].name` then you get "aarsh" as output.

So here you are getting `dish = {id: "1", name: "Omelettes", price: "35.00", image: false, …}`
then you can do like this `dish.name` and you will get Omelettes

Comment: No no. it is like that [{id: "1", name: "Omelettes", price: "35.00", image: false, …}] . After pushing it should become like that, [{id: "1", name: "Omelettes", price: "35.00", image: false, …}, {id: "2", name: "Biriyani", price: "100.00", image: false, …}]. Sorry I missed the array symbol

Comment: Then you can do like this a.push({id:dish.id,name:dish.name,etc ..})
if it works let me know

Comment: The first thing to verify is that he's actually getting into the `isChecked` block. An object is an object and if that block is being reached then it will be pushed onto the array. Since it's not being pushed onto the array then it seems like he's never entering the `isChecked` block. I've written a comment above suggesting that the check be done in the function rather than assuming the property is being correctly accessed in the template.